# Instapaper freezing on startup due to problematic article

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, crash, performance, instapaper

I added an article to Instpaper on my iPod Touch, and then I opened the article. It crashed Instapaper, so I deleted the article through my browser and then reopened Instapaper. Now Instapaper freezes on startup.

Is there any way to stop Instapaper from loading the last opened article, so I can get it out of this loop to fix it?

I already tried removing it from the multitask bar, and restarting my device.

Comment: Remember that you can always delete the Instapaper app on your iPod Touch and then get it again. Logging back into your account should being you to a list view, not an article view.

Comment: I'd rather not delete it though. I know that the articles are saved in the account so they will not be lost, but ideally I'd like to keep my very specific article view settings, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- force quite the Instapaper app again
- login into your Instapaper account on instapaper.com
- remove offending article
- restart Instapaper app

Comment: Removing the article was one of the first things I did. For some reason, I had to do a few extra force quits; only doing it once did not work. I did also open instpaper.com in my browser, without actually doing anything in it (since the offending article was already moved) and perhaps that might have helped, some how. Anyway, it's fixed now, thanks.

Comment: It happened again. This time I just let it load; it took a long time but it eventually finished. For some reason, though, the article itself was bugged. I deleted it through my browser and the article did not disappear from the app, so I had to remove it from the app. The link appeared to be broken for only this one article.

Answer (score 0):

My Instapaper iPad app suddenly started to crash, too. An update of the app was available, but that didn't help.

In my case, there was no particular offending article that caused the crash. I ended up removing the app from the device completely, and then reinstalling it. All my saved articles then showed up without any problems.